# Duplicating UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I can't figure out how could I duplicate `UIView` with its contents. Or is it even possible?

I have made and `UIView` with a label and a button inside a .xib file. Now I wish to copy this view n times only with different label text.

I'm trying to do this like this, but such way I only get the last object shown. `_view1` is `IBOutlet` just like `_view1Label`.

```
    NSMutableArray *Info = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:number.intValue];
    for(int i = 0; i != number.intValue; i++)
    {
        NSString *number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Zona%i ",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"ObjectNumber"].intValue];
        NSString *zona = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i",number, i+1];
        NSString *parinkta = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:zona];
        _view1Label.text = parinkta;
        _view1.hidden = false;
        CGRect newrect = CGRectMake(_view1.frame.origin.x, _view1.frame.origin.y + (80 * i), _view1.frame.size.width, _view1.frame.size.height);
        _view1.frame = newrect;
        [Info addObject:_view1];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i != number.intValue; i++)
    {
        UIView *add = [Info objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.view addSubview:add];
    }
```

I guess you'll get the idea what I am trying to do, maybe my idea of doing this is totaly wrong, so could anyone help me get on the path on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the view multiple times from the nib, adjusting the label contents on each copy you load. This is much easier, shorter, less prone to error than trying to copy the UIView contents in-memory which you're trying to do.

Here's an example of using `UINib` to access the nib contents:

```
 UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"nibName" bundle:nil];
 NSArray *nibContents = [nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil];

 // Now nibContents contains the top level items from the nib.
 // So a solitary top level UIView will be accessible
 // as [nibContents objectAtIndex:0]

 UIView *view = (UIView *)[nibContents objectAtIndex:0];

 // assumes you've set the tag of your label to '1' in interface builder
 UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:1];
 label.text = @"My new text";
```

So just repeat the above code for each nib instance you want.

Comment: Use a `UINib` to do this efficiently.

Comment: Could you be more specific on how to do this? I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge, simple example could make it much more clear

Comment: Updated answer to add small example. Read the API docs if you want to know more!

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to show `n` views then you have to create the view `n` times, inside the first for loop, you can not place a single view in multiple places

Answer (score 0):

If you are created the first view through code then you can use the following method.

Change your for loop like:

```
for(int i = 0; i != number.intValue; i++)
    {
        NSString *number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Zona%i ",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"ObjectNumber"].intValue];
        NSString *zona = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i",number, i+1];
        NSString *parinkta = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:zona];
        UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        UILabel *tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        tempLabel.frame = _view1Label.frame;
        tempLabel.text = _view1Label.text;
        [tempView addSubview: tempLabel];
        tempView.frame = _view1.frame;
        _view1Label.text = parinkta;
        _view1.hidden = false;
        CGRect newrect = CGRectMake(_view1.frame.origin.x, _view1.frame.origin.y + (80 * i), _view1.frame.size.width, _view1.frame.size.height);
        _view1.frame = newrect;
        [Info addObject:tempView];
    }
```

Comment: This might fix the problem with the code he posted, but it also encourages the wrong approach entirely.